# How can I use jQuery $(this) in react js function

Tags: jquery, reactjs, this

I am working on **reactjs** and on click I am calling a function.

In that function I want to use jQuery `$this` to change the text of that element.
Is it possible to do so?

Or is there any way with reactjs to change the current elements text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need just change text for element that was clicked you can do it like this

```
var Component = React.createClass({
    handleClick(e) {
        e.currentTarget.innerHTML = 'New Text';
    },

    render() {
        return <div onClick={this.handleClick}>Change Text</div>;
    }
});
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/69z2wepo/19989/)

and using `jQuery` in our case is not necessary